# /bin/sh: node: command not found - in VScode, running Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Im trying to run this simple code in VSCode for learning Javascript but I keep getting this error:

[Running] node "/var/folders/xr/30nkhmxs7159fblbjtfj2jhw0000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.javascript"
/bin/sh: node: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.014 seconds

I've looked online and have tried changing the CodeRunner Executable Map as I saw in another post but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Thanks!

```js
let admin, name; // can declare two variables at once

name = "John";

admin = name;

alert( admin ); // "John"
```

Comment: looks like it's because `node` cannot be found in your PATH. Can you run the same command in the terminal?

Comment: How do I run the same command in the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check the output of `which node` in the default terminal application. If the output is empty, this means that the path where the `node` binary resides is not in your `$PATH`.
Try to find the location of the `node` executable. After this, check what's the shell you're using by running `echo $SHELL`. If it returns something like `/bin/bash`, create a file(may already exist) named ".bash_profile" or ".bashrc" and there, add the following: `export PATH=$PATH:<location of node>`, replacing `<location of node>` with the actual location of the node binary.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I find the location of the node executable?

Comment: I inputed 'echo $SHELL' in the terminal and it did return with /bin/bash but I have no idea where or how to create the ".bash_profile" or ".bashrc" file.

Comment: How did you install `node`? Via `apt`/`pacman`/`dnf`/`yum`? Via manually copying files? Any other?

Comment: To create a .bashrc file, run the command: `touch ~/.bashrc`. Then open that file using the GUI or run `code ~/.bashrc` for VS Code, and then edit the file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

in this page: [How to run javascript code in Visual studio code? /bin/sh: 1: node: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983472/how-to-run-javascript-code-in-visual-studio-code-bin-sh-1-node-not-found)

dmcquiggin had resolve this problem:

Locate the path to your Node executable, by typing the following command in a terminal:

`which node`

The result will be similar to the following (I use nvm to manage my Node versions, yours might look a little different)

`/home/my_username/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/bin/node`

Make a note of / copy this path.

Open VS Code. Either press Ctrl+, (on Linux), or from the File menu, select Preferences > Settings.
In the search box at the top of this window, type:

`Executor Map`

Click the 'Edit in settings.json' link displayed under the first result.

Add the following to the end of the settings file, replacing the path with the one from step 1.

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
            "javascript": "/home/my_username/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/bin/node"
}
```

this also works on my mac, cheers