# Visual Studio Code - integrated terminal runs in environment I don't recognise

Tags: node.js, linux, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code 1.82.0 installed on Nobara Linux 37 and tried to use it to make a node.js app. Soon I discovered that the Integrated Terminal (`` ctrl+` ``) doesn't recognise `node -v` command:

```
bash-5.1$ node -v
bash: node: command not found
```

The node.js works on regular terminal just fine and compiles code:

```
$ node -v
v18.16.1
```

I found out that gcc works fine on the integrated terminal but the version differs from the desktop terminal:

```
Integrated Terminal:
bash-5.1$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 12.2.0
[...]

Desktop Terminal:
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 12.3.1 20230508 (Red Hat 12.3.1-1)
[...]
```

So I conclude that those environments are somehow different. I checked the `env` command and it turns out that even though I run bash terminal instead of shell terminal (default in vscode), the SHELL parameter points to the sh folder, instead of bash:

```
Integrated Terminal:
bash-5.1$ env
SHELL=/bin/sh
[...]

Desktop Terminal:
$ env
SHELL=/bin/bash
[...]
```

So this is why node isn't working. But how to fix it? Although PATH is different in both terminals, both include correct folder path (`/usr/bin`) for node.js, being located at `/usr/bin/node`. Tried to change terminal from gnome to zsh, didn't help.

Also I think I should mention that the problem began as a series of errors `[xxx preload-host-spawn-strategy]` when running any command, like:

```
bash-5.1$ node -v
[881 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Warning: waitpid override ignores groups
[881 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Warning: waitpid override ignores groups
[881 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Warning: waitpid override ignores groups
bash: node: command not found
[881 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Warning: waitpid override ignores groups
[881 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Warning: waitpid override ignores groups
[881 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Warning: waitpid override ignores groups
```

I fixed it by adding following setting a setting in `settings.json` (fix from user "brianpgordon", second link):

```
{
  [...]
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "LD_PRELOAD": null
  }
}
```

It got rid of the errors, but the initial problem of wrong environment persists. I believe that the Integrated Terminal runs in some kind of sandbox. In previous versions of vscode there was even an actual option to enable/disable the sandbox mode but now it is not available (fix from user "abhigit23", second link).

I also tried to change the terminal profile to all there was `ctrl+shift+p` "Terminal Select Default Profile": bash, bash (2), sh, sh (2).

The problems above are since the very installation of vscode. Extensions installed: `Github Pull Requests and Issues`, `Debugger for Firefox`, but it doubtedly has any impact on the issue.

Related, not helpful:

- [/bin/sh: node: command not found - in VScode, running Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65968241/bin-sh-node-command-not-found-in-vscode-running-javascript)
- https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code/issues/370
- https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code/issues/407

VSCode about:

```
Version: 1.82.0
Commit: 8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314
Date: 2023-09-06T22:07:18.759Z
Electron: 25.8.0
ElectronBuildId: 23503258
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.4.10-202.fsync.fc37.x86_64
```

Comment: You can change which terminal vscode uses

Comment: @Konrad Do You mean: in terminal window, on the right there is `+` and down arrow and then select "bash"? I am using this one already. Or do You mean changing it to the desktop one? If I must, I will do it, but I'd prefer to fix the integrated one.

Comment: what terminal profile are you using? one of the defaults? a custom defined one? what is the definition of the terminal profile in your settings?

Comment: I used all of the deault profiles. I don't know what a terminal definition is. Where to find it, in settings.json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you have installed a flatpack version of VSCode from the Software app in the system. Flatpack isolates the environment of the app from the system. That is why you cannot see all binaries like node from the terminal.

If you expect easy access to the binaries from the VSCode, i would suggest to uninstall flatpack version and install vscode via `dnf` like it is described here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Not sure why you had so many errors in the bash in flatpack version.
For anyone that wants to use the flatpack version i would recommend the link below.

https://raduzaharia.medium.com/using-the-vscode-flatpak-distribution-a275d59ff1c7